# Use WinSCP or any other program (cmd) to download from SFTP

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd.exe, sftp, winscp

How to use WinSCP or any other program (from command-line) to download files from SFTP with authorization key?

This is for Windows versions 10 and 11. I am trying to download files from command prompt (**cmd.exe**) without using the graphical user interface. For example, using a batch file to download the files. The SFTP uses basic string key.

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

In [WinSCP scripting](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation), use [`-privatekey` switch of the `open` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_open#privatekey) to specify the key to authenticate with.

```
open -privatekey=mykey.ppk sftp://username@example.com
get /remote/path/file C:\local\path\file
exit
```